# oracle database, Omitting records from a table which are subset of records in same table based on two columns

Tags: database, plsql, subset

I have some customers which are clustered into groups by cluster_id and the amount of data is huge (So performance is a matter here). The simplest form of what I have is the following table:

cust_id   |    cluster_Id
---------- |  -----------
  1      |   1
  2      |   1
  3      |   1
  2      |   2
  1      |   2
  2      |   3
  4      |   3
  1      |   4

I want those clusters with greatest number of customers such that no costumer be removed. In other words, I want to delete records of a cluster that is subset of another cluster.
In above example, the output table should look like this:

cust_id       cluster_Id
--------  |    ----------
  1      |   1
  2      |   1
  3      |   1
  2      |   3
  4      |   3

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand your question.
"I want to delete records of a cluster that is subset of another cluster" ==>??

Comment: I think what he is trying to say is... because all customers in cluster 2 are also in cluster 1 (making it a subset of cluster one) then don't display cluster 2.... same for cluster 4. Which is why in the output he is only displaying cluster 1 and 3.

Comment: @ShaunPeterson Yes, this is what I meant. by the way I solved this using two loops and comparing each group (by cluster_id) and removing subsets. However I was looking for a query solution rather than algorithmic solution.

Comment: And if you have two clusters that both contain exactly the same set of customers, then you need to ensure that you only delete one of them, right?

Comment: @David Aldridge: Yes!